# Can the Druid heal themselves with the Balance move?

Tags: dungeon-world

Can the character who has the balance move (either from being a druid or acquiring it as a multiclass move) use it on themselves?

> **Balance:** When you deal damage, gain 1 balance. When you touch someone and spend balance you may channel the spirits of life: For each balance spent, heal 1d4 HP.

I feel that the word *someone* includes the user of the move and that it both fits the move as written as well as in spirit (druids are often solitary and being able to heal oneself is a very useful skill) but I'm looking for an official answer if possible or some well reasoned ones if not.

Comment: Welcome to RP Stack Exchange and to Dungeon World in special! There are a few people here that give good DW related answers really quickly. If you have not done so already, you might also want to check out the Dungeon World Tavern on Google+

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, the Druid can heal herself using this move. There is no concern about balance (there almost never is in Dungeon World, because of the 6− possibility can always scale up what is risked to match the magnitude of the advantage sought), and it's certainly flavourful for the Druid to ask the spirits to help her.

I haven't seen official word on *this* move, but Sage has weighed in on an even odder wording in a way consistent with your and my reading of this move. The Wizard's *invisibility* spell says that it targets an "ally", leading groups to assume that the Wizard can't make himself invisible, but Sage's answer was that the Wizard is his own ally and can use the spell on himself.

So if that reading is permissible, this one *definitely* is if we apply Sage's reasoning—the Druid is most definitely "someone."